# What port does allure Jenkins plugin jetty server port listen on

Tags: allure

Allure plugin starts a jetty server for report viewing as I understand it.  What port does it listen on?

Comment: Jetty runs on whatever port you configure it to run. By default, web servers listen for traffic on port 80 for http and port 443 for https.

Answer (score 0):

Web server is only required to view the Allure report locally due to browser security. So Allure Jenkins plugin is only generates the report files and stores those files in workspace, and Jenkins serves report as other files from workspace.